# Google Youtube Api Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am trying to access google youtube API using the auth2.0 method but am unable to get an access
token.

Given Below python code

```
import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client.json"
    channel_id='channeld'

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
```

[image]

[image]

Not Sure What I am missing here ? can you help out any suggestion are welcomed

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the link `error details`. It will tell you the redirect uri your application is sending from.

Take that redirect uri and add it in google developer console, the redirect uri must exactly match.

[Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

## web app vs installed app

The code you are using is designed for an installed application hence the `oogle_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file`  So to use it you need to create [installed application credetials](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/BBgrgA96n-Q) You appear to have done that. This code will open up the web browser consent screen on the machine its running on.   This code is not designed for running on a web server.

## update

Open your credentials.json file there should be two redirect URIs in there delete the urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob one

Comment: error detail does not contain specific uri: The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type. You can create a Client ID for native application at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient

Comment: are you creating a web app or an installed app?  sounds like you created installed credentials and are using code for a web app

Comment: web app. even after keeping one redirect URI issue won't be resolved. Previously I am using the same code and was able to generate an access token. It just simple python code and web client credential

Comment: The code you have is for an installed application not a web application